# sum of count in where clause (or having) in the same table with group by

Tags: mysql

I have a products table with columns `id`, `binno`, `name`, `sku`, `inwarddate` and more.

Each bin stores 20 or 30 products. We need to group by `binno` for dispatch and show sum of items in each bin. That makes the query look like:

```
SELECT  count(*) as total,binno, model, color, sku FROM products
 where location=1 and sku='4'
 GROUP BY binno
```

This is working. It gives the following result:

```
Binno model color sku total
231    3    2      4   20
232    3    2      4   20
...
```

Now I need to select bins where total of this count=500 (or any other number) to limit the results to show 25 bins. Required number may not be 500. it may be any number but the user knows the no of items in a bin (just like ATM user).

I need `sum` of `count(*)` in having or where. That will solve my problem.

Comment: So - for a given `sku`, every bin will have *n* items; depending on the `sku` *n* will be either 20 or 30. And, when looking for a quantity of a given 'sku', you will *always* need *n* * *y* items - you will *always* use all items in a bin. If an item is 20 to a bin, you'll *never* wind up with a bin with 10 items, or 18, or 2.

Comment: So, let's say you need 42 bins of `sku` 4, and there are 207 bins of `sku` 4. And, let's assume the bin ID values happen to be 1-207. Does it matter which 42 bins we return? are bins 1-42, bins 166-207, bins 1,4,7,...,124 (every third bin, starting from 1), all equally valid? Is there some other field that would make some bins better choices than others?

Comment: So you're basically trying to solve the [Knapsack Problem using SQL](http://aprogrammerwrites.eu/?p=560#.WP-StlMrLOQ)? MySQL is not good enough for it, given its weak SQL features.

Comment: actually I need sum of count(*) in having or where. That will solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

First limit the result to 500 (or whatever) and then `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    binno,
    count(*) AS total
FROM 
    ( SELECT binno
      FROM products
      WHERE location = 1 
        AND sku = '4'
      ORDER BY binno             -- the order may be different
      LIMIT 500
    ) AS lim
GROUP BY 
    binno ;
```

Optimal index for this query:

```
INDEX (location, sku, binno)
```

Comment: Optimal: `INDEX(location, sku, binno)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT   count(*) as total, binno, model, color, sku
FROM     products
WHERE    location=1
AND      sku     ='4'
GROUP BY binno
HAVING   total   =500
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually count is 20 for every bin. I need to list first 25 bins where total of sum of these count() for these will be 500( 25*20)